# mysql query distinct and order by

Tags: mysql, distinct

I have a table_A with this structure:

```
|- id_a primary key
|- id_b references table_B(id_b)
|- timestamp
|- varchar_column
```

I need to do a query that joins on table_B, it must be distinct on table_A.id_b, but it has to return also the others columns (not only the distinct one); I also need to get, for each distinct table_a.id_b, the record with the biggest timestamp.
I did like in two ways, but they both return error:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(table_A.id_b) FROM table_A INNER JOIN table_B on table_A.id_b = table_B.id_b ORDER BY table_A.timestamp DESC
```

and this one:

```
SELECT * FROM table_A INNER JOIN table_B on table_A.id_b = table_B.id_b ORDER BY table_A.timestamp DESC GROUP BY table_A.id_b
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an inner join on table_a for id_b and max(timestamp) and join the rest of the tables

```
select * 
from table_A a
Inner join (
    select id_b, max(timestamp) my_time
    from table_A
    group by id_b
) t on t.id_b = a.id_b and t.my_time = a.timestamp
inner join table_B on a.id_b = table_B.id_b 
ORDER BY a.timestamp DESC
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Using you query I get this error: #1054 - Unknown column 'table_A.id_b' in 'on clause'

Comment: asnwer  updated ..  using a instead of table_A in second inner join